# Here I have some confusion regarding the Python package installations

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, xlrd, xlwt

Hi I just installed `Python 2.7` as I have some requirements to code. Now I am also interested to install some python packages too as per my requirement.

I have downloaded some `tar.zip` packages like `beautifulsoup4`,`xlrd 0.8.0`,`xlwt 0.7.4` and `beautifulsoup4 4.1.3` from the respective sites. Now I unzipeed them to `C:\Python27\` and now if I run from this folder `python setup.py install` will it work for me? means all the required files will be downloaded to its respective folders.

Please guide me to understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required files are already in the folders and that command installs it. You have to enter in the each unzipped folders and run `python setup.py install`. If all works right now you have these modules installed where the python can find them.

For more info read this link: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/24/python-101-setting-up-python-on-windows/

Comment: If I don't add it to the `PATH` variable then what could be happened and how to run my scripts, just to increase my knowledge.

Comment: If you don't add what to the `PATH`? if you refer to the `python` executable then `python setup.py install` won't work; you can use the absolute path to the `python` executable. Furthemore, python use its own environment variable to find the modules, `PYTHONPATH`, maybe this can be useful: http://mirnazim.org/writings/python-ecosystem-introduction/

Comment: Okay! according to you if don't add the following two lines: ;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts , to run any .py file everytime i have to go to the `C:\Python27\Script\` directory and run it as   'python MyTest.py`. And If add it to the `path` then I can run all `.py` files of mine from the directory `C:\Users\Tukai>` . Am I right? please correct me!!!

Comment: I'm not a Windows expert and I don't know how it manages to execute `.py` files: I think if you add to the `PATH` the directory containing the windows python executable, you can launch python files from any path assuming you use `python MyTest.py` in the directory where `MyTest.py` is.